# Make `npm install --save` add a strict version to package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, version, package.json

When you run `npm install --save somepackage`, it usually adds something like this into package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "somepackage": "^2.1.0"
}
```

Because the version is prepended with a caret(^), this means that if you later run `npm install`, it might install version 2.3.0 instead. This can be undesirable for fairly obvious reasons. `npm shrinkwrap` is useful, but doesn't really solve the problem.

So, I have several questions:

1. When installing a package, is it possible to specify that you want it to be set to a specific version in package.json (no caret before the version number)?
2. When publishing a package to npm, is there any way to prevent the default of including the caret before the version when other developers install your package?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

To specify by default a exact version, you can change your npm config with [`save-exact`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#save-exact):

```
npm config set save-exact true
```

You can also specify the prepend version with a tilde with [`save-prefix`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#save-prefix).

And, no you can't force user to update to a minor or a patch version, NPM uses [semver](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver) and it's the recommend way of publishing packages.

Comment: If you only want to do this for a specific package, you can add `--save-exact` to the command line.  Eg, `npm install --save --save-exact somepackage`.

Comment: this only just save the exact versions of your `top level packges` - the ones specified in `package.json`, but won't work for any packages that `top level packages` are depends on. https://yarnpkg.com/ solving that problem with `yarn.lock` file so you have always exact versions of all of your packages.

Comment: This should be the default behaviour

Answer (score 28):

You can change the default behaviour by using the `--save-exact` option.

```
// npm
npm install --save --save-exact react

// yarn
yarn add --exact react
```

I created a blog post about this if anyone is looking for this in the future.

https://www.dalejefferson.com/blog/how-to-save-exact-npm-package-versions/

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.
Additionally, in you case, don't say "I've explained the code in my blog post", but include the majority of the content here, and use the link only as a reference

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Chade, I've added more detail.

Comment: Blog is 404 now

Answer (score 4):

Run:

```
npm install --save --save-exact my-module@my-specific-version
```

<sub>Adding an answer to make [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656189/make-npm-install-save-add-a-strict-version-to-package-json#comment61662105_30659125) easier to see.</sub>