# Using NPM and linking, how do I update transitive dependencies of a linked project?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm using NPM 3.8.0. I have a project B that depends on my project A. Project A has N external dependencies. I have linked my project A into project B using `npm link A` within project B. This all works fine so I am able to make changes in project A and see those changes immediately within project B.

Now I go and upgrade some of those N dependencies in project A and want to get the updates within my project B as well. I run `npm update` within project A and see the updates within its node_modules top level directory. Now I go to project B and `npm update`. I do not get project A's updated dependencies in its top level node_modules directory. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make \`npm install --save\` add a strict version to package.json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656189/make-npm-install-save-add-a-strict-version-to-package-json)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check versions in package json against actual node\_modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061525/check-versions-in-package-json-against-actual-node-modules)